Is it possible to give the third dimension of LSTMs the size of the signals?
I am working on an LSTM autoencoder and have a few questions, please:
Is it possible to use the third dimension of the LSTM for the size of the signals?
The reason I ask is that when I set the size of my signal (which is 1600 time step) as the second dimension of the LSTM autoencoder, it cannot reconstruct the signal. However, when I set the signal size in the third dimension, the autoencoder reconstructs the signal perfectly.
What is the maximum size of the signal that can be used in the LSTM?
When I use the second dimension (sequence length), the LSTM autoencoder struggles to reconstruct the signal when the signal size exceeds 120 time samples. Why does this happen?
Note: The input dimensions for the LSTM are in the format (batch_size, sequence_length, features).
When I use the second dimension (sequence length), the LSTM autoencoder struggles to reconstruct the signal when the signal size exceeds 120 time samples. Why does this happen?
Note: The input dimensions for the LSTM are in the format (batch_size, sequence_length, features).
